# How to use filter condition along with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, filtering

I am trying to filter the dataset with multiple columns and by filtering with a particular value in the column using groupby . I am able to filter using groupby but not able to apply the filter

I have tried using below code

```
df.groupby(['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision'])['winner'].size()
```

**Actual result :** giving me all city details (i.e) Cape Town, Centurion and Chandigarh

**expected result:** I just want city details where city is equal to 'Cape Town'

Please check the screenshot attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Filter city=CapeTown first and then groupby:

```
out = (df.query("city =='Cape Town'")
         .groupby(['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision'])['winner'].size())
```